# Add additional data to dygraphs point

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible in dygraph to add additional data to a point?

For example:

```
X, Y, myId
[
[1, 2, 'some id value'],
[1, 2, 'some other id value'],
[1, 2, 'some value']
]
```

And then be able to get myId again in drawPointCallback for instance, so I can decide how to draw a point based on the type of value.

Or: when the user clicks on a point, some click callback fires and I can obtain this id to do further actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to store a number, you could put it in a hidden series. Or you could use an auxiliary array with the same number of entries as your data has rows, e.g.

```js
var data = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]];
var auxiliary = ['some id value', 'some other id value', 'some value'];
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  pointClickCallback: function(e, pt) {
    console.log(auxiliary[pt.idx]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! A hidden series works nice. The drawPointCallback method signature in the api docs misses the last parameter idx, I didn't know it was there.

Comment: I was surprised by that omission, too. I filed issue [#471](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/471) for it.