# add additional data to legend Dypraphs

Tags: dygraphs

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976363/add-additional-data-to-dygraphs-point) about adding extra data into current data. Is there any way to show this additional data in the label/legend together with the numeric data?

Comment: Hi @Justine, in that post you comment the info is shown when the user clicks on a point. Do you want that exactly functionality or you want to show the additional data always in the legend?

Comment: Hi @LucidioVacas :) but it only show in console and when i try`valueFormatter: function(x) {
                         return auxiliary[pt.idx]}

Comment: But do you want to show the additional info when clicking over the point or when the mouse is over?

Comment: mouse over.. I want it to show in the legend

Comment: hi @LucidioVacas sorry fr being so messy :P can u take a look at this jfid [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kck5ygd4/1/) the additional data is undefined in the legend

Comment: Hi @Justine, I am not at home. I Will take a look when I have a moment ;)

Comment: Hi @LucidioVacas, I've found a way to display the additional data..Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was wrong because you was trying to use the code from the other post in the same way without realizing the differences. Next time, try to debug a little more your code, doing some effort in looking for the failures.

You say that you get undefined when you plot auxiliary[x.idx]. If you simply do console.log(x), you will notice that x is the timestamp value, an integer, so you can´t obtain a correct index to look for in the array for the additional data.

If you see the [dygraphs API](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html), there is a function *getRowForX(xVal)* that you can use to find the row number corresponding to a x-value. So I have used that funcion in the value formatter to get the correct index to access the additional data in the array.

I have modified your code and I think it is working the way you need. Below you have the snippet [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lucidio/kck5ygd4/2/). I hope this would be useful for you.

```js
var auxiliary = [
   'ID1',
    'ID2', 
      'ID3', 
    'ID4',
      'ID5', 
      'ID6'
  ];


new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("container"),
    [
        [new Date("2016/2/3"), [1,3,6], [4,4,4]],
        [new Date("2016/3/3"), [1,3,6], [3,3,3]],
        [new Date("2016/4/3"), [1,3,6], [1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016/5/3"), [1,3,6], [2,2,2]],
        [new Date("2016/6/3"), [1,3,6], [6,6,6]],
        [new Date("2016/7/3"), [1,3,6], [5,5,5]]
    ],
{
    labels: [ "Date", "SD" , "Scatter"],
    showRangeSelector: true,
    customBars: true,
    drawPoints: true,
    series: {
        "SD" : {

        },
        "Scatter" : {
            customBars: false,
            strokeWidth: 0.0
        }
 },
    axes: {
        x: {
   valueFormatter: function() {
        index = this.getSelection();
    return auxiliary[index];
   }
  },
 includeZero: true
 }

}
);
```

```css
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome! Anyway, if you consider my answer as valid, please accept it ;)